# Unknown provider: $intervalProvider <- $interval <- infiniteScrollDirective

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to load the data using ngInfinitescroll but getting the error which  do not understand why it comes though declared all the required dependencies. Here my work http://jsfiddle.net/ey0c2n1t/

```
   <div class="clusterize">
  <table infinite-scroll="loadMore()"  infinite-scroll-distance="1">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Headers</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
  </table>
  <div>
    <table> 
      <tbody>

        <tr ng-repeat="value in dataFilter = (data | limitTo:numberToDisplay)">
             <td>{{value.id}}</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
```

**JS**

```
var App = angular.module('App', ['infinite-scroll']);

App.directive('whoiam', function($http) {
    return {
        restrict: 'EA',
        templateUrl: 'whoiam.html',
        controller: ctrlr
        }
        function ctrlr($scope) {    

       $scope.data = [];
       $scope.numberToDisplay = 100;

    $http.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/comments').success(function(data) {
            $scope.data = data;
        });

         loadMore = function() {
      alert("test");
        if (this.numberToDisplay + 5 <  $scope.data.length) {
            this.numberToDisplay += 5;
        } else {
            this.numberToDisplay =  $scope.data.length;
        }
    }

    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The version of AngularJS (v1.0.3) you are referencing in your project is incompatible with the version of `ngInfiniteScroll` (v1.3.0) you are referencing.

This error is telling you that the `infiniteScrollDirective` is attempting to inject the `$interval` service, however a provider for this service cannot be found.

This is because the $interval service was not available in AngularJS 1.0.3.

Updating the version of AngularJS in your sample to a more recent release (v1.4.8) resolves the error.

Note that the `bower.json` file for the `ngInfiniteScroll` project has a dependency on AngularJS versions >= 1.2x.

```
"dependencies": {
  "angular": ">=1.2.0"
}
```

Comment: Are you still getting the `Unknown provider: $intervalProvider <- $interval <- infiniteScrollDirective` error after upgrading AngularJS?