# How to use nginfinitescroll plug-in inside directive

Tags: angularjs

I have created a directive for the list of data display. And now I wanted to apply infinitescroll (as child) directive for the lazy loading inside the parent directive. Unfortunately it is not firing the parent directive method called load more `infinite-scroll="loadmore()"`. [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/2vrL6pj0/2/) my sample work.

what is my mistake to fire the method?

Comment: I see you have taken my advice from your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54862440/unknown-provider-intervalprovider-interval-infinitescrolldirective/54864660#54864660). If you could please review or accept my answer (if it was helpful), I'd be happy to look into this for you...

Comment: I followed your inputs but still it is not working for some reason

Comment: "Not working" is different from the problem you reported in the previous question. I feel you agree, given you have now raised a new question and have updated your sample following my advice. Like I said, I'd be happy to help you get this working - however I feel you should recognize my help getting you this far.

Comment: Agree and thank you. Expecting your valuable inputs for this question.